# How to translate "Systems Software Engineer"?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, этимология, выражения

How does one officially and accurately translate the job title of "Systems Software Engineer", for example, [bls.gov's "15-1133 Software Developers, Systems Software"](http://www.bls.gov/oes/2014/may/oes151133.htm), into Russian Russian?

To give a bit more context, let me quote how US Bureau of Labor Statistics describes this job title:

> 15-1133 Software Developers, Systems Software
>
> Research, design, develop, and test operating systems-level software, compilers, and network distribution software for medical, industrial, military, communications, aerospace, business, scientific, and general computing applications. Set operational specifications and formulate and analyze software requirements. May design embedded systems software. Apply principles and techniques of computer science, engineering, and mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 5):

System Software Engineer - Системный инженер-программист / системный программист

Software Developers, Systems Software - Разработчики (программисты), системное ПО (программное обеспечение).

If you look for some official title from the government, you could refer [this document](http://professions.org.ru/?okz=2132) or [this one](http://www.etks.info/okpdtr/office/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82). I found also one more [link](http://base.garant.ru/1548770/), which looks more complete.

From [etks.info](http://www.etks.info/okz/group-2132.html):

```
    Программисты

Программисты разрабатывают записывают проверяют программы, реализующие решение различных технических, экономических и других задач с помощью компьютерной техники, а также осуществляют их сопровождение и обслуживание.

Их обязанности включают:

    изучение целей решаемых задач требований к результатам, определение объемов структуры источников информации подлежащей обработке на вычислительных машинах макетов и схем ее ввода, обработки, хранения, выдачи и контроля;
    описание задач с помощью математических моделей и алгоритмов, составление и запись программ на языках программирования высокого уровня и машинно-ориентированных языках;
    отладку разработанных программ и их корректировку в процессе доработки;
    определение возможности использования в решении задач готовых программ разработанных другими разработчиками (учреждениями, организациями, предприятиями);
    разработку и внедрение методов автоматизированного программирования типовых и стандартных программ управляющих, обрабатывающих сервисных программ инструкций по их использованию, входных алгоритмических языков;
    участие в работах по унификации и типизации вычислительных процессов, расширению области применения вычислительной техники;
    обслуживание компьютерных программ и соответствующей документации заключающееся в их обновлении и корректировке в соответствии с изменением входных и выходных данных, спецификаций или состава оборудования, вычислительных средств;
    выполнение родственных по содержанию обязанностей;
    руководство другими работниками.
```

The list of professions:

- Программист
- Инженер-программист
- Инженер - системный программист (amendment #5 from 2004)

Comment: I'd like to add that though formally System Software Engineer is translated as "Системный инженер-программист", "Системный программист" is used far more often, for example, Google gives 202k results for latter phrase vs. 52k for former.

Comment: @YaroslavSkudarnov Thanks for the note; it seems that Engineer title is not so prestigious nowadays in Russia as it used to be. It still means something in Europe.

Comment: I think the point is not only in prestige, but in the fact that in Russian culture nowadays "engineer" is usually associated with those professions who develop something tangible, material, not IT-product.

Comment: Also, "инженер-программист" has formal undertone and usually is used in descriptions of vacancies and specialties, so probably topic-starter needs extactly it.

Comment: Frankly, I was kinda looking for the official job designation from some kind of the labour bureau, but a google search revealed a list of prehistoric soviet occupations instead. :-)

Comment: @cnst I included the link in my answer

Comment: @UVV, great!  I somehow couldn't find it myself on professions.org.ru; however, you've included two links, and they seem to provide different descriptions.  Do you know why?  Also, for a complete answer, could you kindly quote the relevant information from the links, to ensure the answer is self-sufficient?

Answer (score -1):

The latest information about official description of occupations and positions you can find (in Russian) here http://profstandart.rosmintrud.ru/
There are a lot of different documents but not much of direct pages so I extract for you description for the Engineer-Software developer (software developer)

ИНЖЕНЕР-ПРОГРАММИСТ (ПРОГРАММИСТ)

Должностные обязанности.

На основе анализа математических моделей и алгоритмов решения экономических и других задач разрабатывает программы, обеспечивающие возможность выполнения алгоритма и соответственно поставленной задачи средствами вычислительной техники, проводит их тестирование и отладку.

Разрабатывает технологию решения задачи по всем этапам обработки информации.

Осуществляет выбор языка программирования для описания алгоритмов и структур данных.

Определяет информацию, подлежащую обработке средствами вычислительной техники, ее объемы, структуру, макеты и схемы ввода, обработки, хранения и вывода, методы ее контроля.

Выполняет работу по подготовке программ к отладке и проводит отладку.

Определяет объем и содержание данных контрольных примеров, обеспечивающих наиболее полную проверку соответствия программ их функциональному назначению.

Осуществляет запуск отлаженных программ и ввод исходных данных, определяемых условиями поставленных задач.

Проводит корректировку разработанной программы на основе анализа выходных данных.

Разрабатывает инструкции по работе с программами, оформляет необходимую техническую документацию.

Определяет возможность использования готовых программных продуктов. Осуществляет сопровождение внедренных программ и программных средств.

Разрабатывает и внедряет системы автоматической проверки правильности программ, типовые и стандартные программные средства, составляет технологию обработки информации.

Выполняет работу по унификации и типизации вычислительных процессов.

Принимает участие в создании каталогов и картотек стандартных программ, в разработке форм документов, подлежащих машинной обработке, в проектировании программ, позволяющих расширить область применения вычислительной техники.

Должен знать: 
руководящие и нормативные материалы, регламентирующие методы разработки алгоритмов и программ и использования вычислительной техники при обработке информации; 
основные принципы структурного программирования; 
виды программного обеспечения; 
технико-эксплуатационные характеристики, конструктивные особенности, назначение и режимы работы ЭВМ, правила ее технической эксплуатации; 
технологию автоматической обработки информации; 
виды технических носителей информации;
методы классификации и кодирования информации; 
формализованные языки программирования; 
действующие стандарты, системы счислений, шифров и кодов; 
порядок оформления технической документации; 
передовой отечественный и зарубежный опыт программирования и использования вычислительной техники; 
основы экономики, организации производства, труда и управления; 
основы трудового законодательства; 
правила и нормы охраны труда.

Требования к квалификации.

Инженер-программист I категории: высшее профессиональное (техническое или инженерно-экономическое) образование и стаж работы в должности инженера-программиста II категории не менее 3 лет.

Инженер-программист II категории: высшее профессиональное (техническое или инженерно-экономическое) образование и стаж работы в должности инженера-программиста III категории или других инженерно-технических должностях, замещаемых специалистами с высшим профессиональным образованием, не менее 3 лет.

Инженер-программист III категории: высшее профессиональное (техническое или инженерно-экономическое) образование и опыт работы по специальности, приобретенный в период обучения, или стаж работы на инженерно-технических должностях без квалификационной категории.

Инженер-программист: высшее профессиональное (техническое или инженерно-экономическое) образование без предъявления требований к стажу работы или среднее профессиональное (техническое или инженерно-экономическое) образование и стаж работы в должности техника I категории не менее 3 лет либо других должностях, замещаемых специалистами со средним профессиональным образованием, не менее 5 лет.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  However, this is unreadable; could you please edit the answer to at least include some line breaks?  Also, I'm specifically interested in Systems one, isn't there such a subcategory within the Software Engineer one?

Comment: Done formatting. Sorry for the inconvenience. Regarding System - I can't find anything specific about this. Maybe my understanding is not correct - does this relate more to soft or hardware?

Comment: Systems is on the intersection of software and hardware, mostly includes embedded work these days (writing arch and device driver support etc), plus the traditional operating systems stuff.

Comment: Where exactly did you find the Russian text you quoted from?  I can't seem to find anything useful on the seemingly-official site (the one you've linked to) itself.

Comment: I found it in me legal database which I use for the work. This text is hidden in the depth of Mintrud's _Postanovlenie_ № 37 dated 21 August 1998. That's why I gave citation and not the exact link. If you give me your email I can send you full text of this document (or maybe there is another way to send files on this website?).

Comment: Perhaps you can take a few screenshots, and post them here in your answer, then?